# Django set default data

Tags: django, django-models

I would like my application to set default data values to some of the tables. I can do it by editing the migration files, but I need a easy and efficient way  to change / update the default values. Any ideas on how I can achive this? Ideally I would like to maintain all my default data in a separate file and insert/update only  when necessary.

Comment: See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

Comment: You want to change data in th db or change the default column values for new entries?

Comment: Change data is db. eg;- Some of the options users can select are stored in the db

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) (or [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)) in your migration. In this function you should look for the instances (or rows) that has value empty and fill it with your default.

Below the RunPython, add a migration to set the [field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default) so any new object will take this value by default